# Migrate from HP-UX to Linux (Shell)

Tags: linux, shell, hp-ux

I want to know what are key things I need to concentrate to migrate HP-UX shell to Linux shell.

Any help will be warmly appreciated!

Note: I didn't find any similar post / question that might help me.

Comment: By HP Linux do you actually mean HP/UX?

Comment: yes exactly , i meant this

Comment: Still, it's very broad. You must make more specific questions. For example, commands to accomplish a task in HP/UX and are not available in Linux and you need alternatives. Or perhaps any scripts that worked under HP/UX and don't under Linux.

Comment: My first thing would be trying to recreate the purpose on the new system using the old system as template, and then search or ask question in how to accomplish these.

Comment: @Krackout.  Never heard of an OS called HP/UX.  However these is an OS called `HP-UX`

Answer (score 1):

For the shell itself, not much at all. The HP/UX default shell for regular users, `/usr/bin/sh`, is a POSIX standard-compliant shell, and the `bash` shell that is common on Linux is mostly a superset of it. If you preferred to use `ksh`, in most distributions you can get the exact same shell on Linux - although it might need to be explicitly selected for installation in the package manager, and on Linux the release version of the shell is likely to be considerably newer than what it was on HP/UX so there may be some differences.

If the question is interpreted more widely to consider not just the shell itself but the command-line tools in general, it's roughly similar to transitioning from HP/UX to Oracle Solaris or IBM AIX. As a rule of thumb, the more closely the commands are involved with actual hardware, the more differences you will encounter.

On HP/UX, you may have viewed the GNU tools as optional expanded versions of corresponding basic OS tools; on Linux, GNU tools usually are the default ones.

If your command/script manipulates regular files or directories, you can probably move the script from HP/UX to Linux as-is or with very small modifications.

If it manipulates network routes or IP addresses? You might use the same commands, but the syntax and options will have significant differences.

Dealing with hardware configuration? You'll have to learn some new commands and procedures altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation!!

Comment: The OS is called HP-UX - not HP/UX.  The Korn shell on recent versions of Linux is `ksh2000`, a project that ended in flames,  is a badly flawed "rewrite" of `ksh93v` and  is not fully compatible with the version of the Korn shell on HP-UX.